# Calling a request from foursquare

Tags: python, function, foursquare

I am trying to use the below function to retrieve venues for different locations but I keep getting this error and I can't figure it out because I used it before and it worked perfectly but with different locations. Please help!

```
def getNearbyVenues(names, latitudes, longitudes, radius=500):

    venues_list=[]
    for name, lat, lng in zip(names, latitudes, longitudes):
        print(name)

        # create the API request URL
        url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?&client_id={}&client_secret={}&v={}&ll={},{}&radius={}&limit={}'.format(
            CLIENT_ID, 
            CLIENT_SECRET, 
            VERSION, 
            lat, 
            lng, 
            radius, 
            LIMIT)

        # make the GET request
        results = requests.get(url).json()["response"]['groups'][0]['items']

        # return only relevant information for each nearby venue
        venues_list.append([(
            name, 
            lat, 
            lng, 
            v['venue']['name'], 
            v['venue']['location']['lat'], 
            v['venue']['location']['lng'],  
            v['venue']['categories'][0]['name']) for v in results])

    nearby_venues = pd.DataFrame([item for venue_list in venues_list for item in venue_list])
    nearby_venues.columns = ['Neighbourhood', 
                  'Neighbourhood Latitude', 
                  'Neighbourhood Longitude', 
                  'Venue', 
                  'Venue Latitude', 
                  'Venue Longitude', 
                  'Venue Category']

    return(nearby_venues)`
```

```
london_venues = getNearbyVenues(names=df['Location'],
                                   latitudes=df['Latitude'],
                                   longitudes=df['Longitude']
                                  )
```

This is the error I am getting

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-180-4f13fb178c94> in <module>
      1 london_venues = getNearbyVenues(names=df['Location'],
      2                                    latitudes=df['Latitude'],
----> 3                                    longitudes=df['Longitude']
      4                                   )

<ipython-input-177-d194f1c67c83> in getNearbyVenues(names, latitudes, longitudes, radius)
     16 
     17         # make the GET request
---> 18         results = requests.get(url).json()["response"]['groups'][0]['items']
     19 
     20         # return only relevant information for each nearby venue

KeyError: 'groups'
```

Comment: can you please share your data frame? and make results =  requests.get(url).json() and print it and show the output

Answer (score 0):

you might have exceeded your API call limit if you are using sandbox account, or there is no such key named "groups". If not, then please provide the coordinates of the location.